# Does option "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" exist in process builder?

Tags: process-builder

In Workflow rules while updating a field we have a option to check **"Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change".**

I just want to know, do we have such option in Process Builder?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its possible.

[image]

You can do this while adding the object. If you check the Yes checkbox under Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction? the record will be re-evaluated maximum of 5 times in same transaction.

[Reevaluate Records in the Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_advanced_reevaluate.htm&language=en_US) for your reference

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting the object from which the process will fire, hit that little "Advanced" chevron and check the box next to "Allow Recursion".